# D3 Method of Appending Images to a Table Header

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In HTML, the way I typically add an image to a table header is as follows:

```
<th><img src= image.png alt="" height=20 width=20></img></th>
```

The HTML way is very straight forward and intuitive. Yet, I have since switched to D3 to create tables, and my header code is:

```
var columns = ['Column X', 'Column Y', 'Column Z']

var table = d3.select('#table_container').append('table'),
    thead = table.append('thead')
    tbody = table.append('tbody');

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
        .text(function(column) { return column; });
```

**My question is:** How can I append images to the table headers using d3? I intend to use a different image for each header.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append an `img` and use `src` as its attribute:

```js
var columns = [
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/77c71e95885bf94c06c7c68ccb63b131.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/9f8cd17bf12b1667d6c4b31b889b3034.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/b4/256/4ece97792658df143eb693c23bb991f3.png"}
];

var table = d3.select("body").append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {
        return d.src;
    });
```

```css
table, th {
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After experimenting more with this, I'm still wondering what if instead of appending the images to a new header row, I instead append images to an existing header. I tried removing `.append('th')` but that resulted in images appended being appended vertically (not across all columns).

Comment: That seems to be an HTML problem to me. As I'm not a specialist in HTML, here is a suggestion: post a new question with your problem, removing the D3 code from it (I mean, ask about the HTML aspect of it) and with the HTML tag only. That way, you'll get more attention.

Comment: @ArashHowaida reading your comment above I couldn't understand your problem, but reading your new question it was clear! That's why I always suggest people posting a new question when you have a new problem. I left an answer there. Cheers.