# Append Image to Existing Table Header

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tableheader

I have created a table, and I would like to add an image to the header. I am using a library called D3.js to create the table. The code is as follows:

```
var columns = [
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/77c71e95885bf94c06c7c68ccb63b131.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/9f8cd17bf12b1667d6c4b31b889b3034.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/b4/256/4ece97792658df143eb693c23bb991f3.png"}
];

var table = d3.select("body").append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {
        return d.src;
    });
```

This code is from my related D3 post:

[D3 Method of Appending Images to a Table Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177459/d3-method-of-appending-images-to-a-table-header)

The code is mostly for context, I'm interested in how native HTML deals with this method. As that will have bearing on how I will use other libraries.

**The issue is:** I can append images to the table as a new header row, but I cannot seem to append images to an existing header row.

In other words, after I create the headers with text titles, I want to add images next to the text titles (different images per column).

Just speculating from my experience so far and going on the advice of a D3 expert, this issue might be an html specific one.

In native HTML can one append images to a header after creating it? What else could native HTML bring to bear for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this table:

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Header 1</th>
   <th>header2</th>
   <th>header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>foo</td>
   <td>bar</td>
   <td>baz</td>
</tr>
```

To append the images to the headers of that **already existing** table, just select the headers and, without any "enter" selection, append the images:

```
d3.selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {
        return d.src;
    });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var columns = [
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/77c71e95885bf94c06c7c68ccb63b131.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/9f8cd17bf12b1667d6c4b31b889b3034.png"}, 
    {src:"http://iconbug.com/data/b4/256/4ece97792658df143eb693c23bb991f3.png"}
];

d3.selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {
        return d.src;
    });
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Header 1</th>
   <th>header2</th>
   <th>header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>foo</td>
   <td>bar</td>
   <td>baz</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That ended up working nicely. We don't need `.enter()` because we assume the header will retain the image throughout right? Or why exactly do we omit it?

Comment: We omit the `enter` because you're not appending new elements based on data, you're simply binding the data to elements that already exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`Html` is completely static, so once you've created it you can't use further `html` to manipulate it.  To dynamically manipulate `html` we use JavaScript (which is how `d3` does its magic).

So I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

If you'd like to include text before the images in the headers using `d3`, you would use `.text()`

For instance,

```
var columns = [
    {title: "Brrmm Brrmm", src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/77c71e95885bf94c06c7c68ccb63b131.png"}, 
    {title: "Race Me", src:"http://iconbug.com/data/3a/256/9f8cd17bf12b1667d6c4b31b889b3034.png"}, 
    {title: "Faster! Faster!", src:"http://iconbug.com/data/b4/256/4ece97792658df143eb693c23bb991f3.png"}
];

var table = d3.select("body").append('table');
var thead = table.append('thead');

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .append('span')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.title;
    })
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {
        return d.src;
    });
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdzKKg

Comment: The `append('span')` I have above is not necessary

Comment: Oh that's good to know, maybe next time I can add the text and icons at the same time. Love the header texts btw!